Помощь по passwd/adduser
Как одной командой поменять пароль? Можно ли как-то сразу ввести пароль?
Такой же вопрос по поводу adduser, можно ли как-то в аргументах ввести пароль?
Ubuntu

man useradd и man chpasswd

echo 'ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ:ПАРОЛЬ' | chpasswd 


Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы.
